# Recolor images with imagick

Tags: image, image-processing, imagemagick, imagick

I'm using Imagick to recolor an image. I want the image to be 'redscale', i.e., to have a gradient of colors going from black to red. With try and error I found these functions:

```
$im = new Imagick('img.jpg');
$im->modulateImage(100, 0, 100); // Grayscale
$im->recolorImage(array(0, 0, 1, 0)); // Cyan?
$im->modulateImage(100, 100, 0); // Red?
$im->writeImage('img2.jpg');
$im->destroy();
```

It works, but I don't understand what recolorImage does. Can anybody explain it with different arrays?

Comment: [`Imagick::recolorImage`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.recolorimage.php) use a color matrix (5 × 5 or 6 × 6). As is explained in [ImageMagic docs](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#color-matrix) it works like [Adobe Flash does](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filters/ColorMatrixFilter.html#matrix)